# Split String Returning only first value

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

My split string code is only returning the first value for some reason. I cannot figure this out so any help would be appreciated. I am using the following.

```
declare @CYEnd varchar(4) = '2015, 2016, 2017'
SELECT * FROM vwRMSGrantsSpending
WHERE CYEnd IN (select ltrim(item) from dbo.SplitStringList(@CYEnd, ','))
```

This should be returning 2015, 2016, and 2017. But it is only returning 2015.

Here is dbo.SplitStringList

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitStringList](@ListString nvarchar(max), @delim 
varchar(2) = ',')
returns @vals table (Item nvarchar(60))
as 
begin
  declare @CurLoc int, @Item nvarchar(60)
  while len(@ListString) > 0
  begin
    set @CurLoc = charindex(@delim, @ListString, 1)
    if @CurLoc = 0
      begin
        set @Item = @ListString
              set @Item = Ltrim(RTrim(@Item))
        set @ListString = ''
      end
    else
      begin
        set @Item = left(@ListString, @CurLoc - 1)
              set @Item = Ltrim(RTrim(@Item))
        set @ListString = substring(@ListString, @CurLoc + 1, 
Len(@ListString) - @CurLoc)
      end
    insert into @vals (Item) values (@Item)  
    end
    return
end
```

Comment: Why there is space before comma for the delimiter? it should be without space or after inside single quotes ', ')

Comment: sorry there should be no space. I was just trying that, i will edit it. Still doesn't work.

Comment: What is dbo.SplitStringList?

Comment: Edited to show dbo.SplitStringList

Comment: Why are you using a `WHILE`? There are loads of dataset approaches out there, such as the XML splitter and DelimitedSplit8k (or for 2012 DelimitedSplit8k_lead). A loop like that is going to be awful for performance; especially if you're splitting against a column in a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you defined the varchar too small.

```
declare @CYEnd varchar(4) = '2015, 2016, 2017'
```

If you run this `PRINT @CYEnd` after the declare you will see that the variable is only equal to `2015`.

Make that variable bigger and it works.